# Format of CSV not correct?

Tags: perl, excel, powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I am generating a CSV with EXPORT-CSV in Powershell and then feeding it to a Perl script. But Perl is unable to import the file.

I have verified the CSV-file against a working version (that has been exported from the same Perl-script and not powershell) and there are NO difference. The coloumns are excactly the same and they both have semicolon as delimiter. If I open the file in Excel however everything ends up in the first cell on each line (meaning I have to do a text-to-coloumns). The working file ends up in a different cells from the start..

To add to the confusion: when I open the file in notepad and copy/paste the contents to a new file the import works!

So, what am I missing? Are there "hidden" properties that I cannot spot with Notepad? Do I have to change the encoding-type?

Please help:)

Comment: Are you using a module (like Text::CSV) or are you parsing the CSV file yourself? I strongly suggest to use a well tested module.

Comment: What is the exact command you are using in Powershell? Don't just say what you are doing, show it.

Comment: I am using a import script that came with the nConf software. I believe it is based on Text::CSV. I am not in front of my code right now Mano, but I will post the exact command as soon as I am. Thank you!

Comment: I tried `dir C:\ | export-csv C:\t.csv` from PS v2 and opened it with Excel 2010 and it displayed data in separate cells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a better look at your CSV files try using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). This will tell you the file encoding in the status bar. Also turn on hidden characters (View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters). This will reveal if there are just line feeds, or carriage returns + line feeds, tabs vs spaces etc... You can also change the file encoding from the Encoding menu. This may help you identify the differences. Notepad doesn't display any of this information.

**Update** - Here's how to convert a text file from Windows to Unix format in code:

```
$allText = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\test.csv") -replace "`r`n?", "`n" 
$encoding = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding    
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\test2.csv", $allText, $encoding)
```

Or you can use Notepad++ (Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix Format).

Comment: This was a fantastic tip! I did indeed open the files per your description and sure enough, my broken version had a CR LF at the end of each line and the working one had only LF. I've read up on the issue and as I understand this has something to do with win/unix type files. But how do I remove the CRs? Or should I export the file with a different encoding with export-csv ? (tried both Utf-8 and standard..)

Comment: @Sune CR+LF is the Windows way, in Unix only LF is needed so it sounds like the Perl script is expecting to live in a Unix world. We can convert the file though. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: In general it isn't necessary to convert the file. Just change the way Perl reads it.

Comment: @BradGilbert It sounds like the OP is using a third party Perl script. It may make more sense for him to just convert the file instead of re-factoring the Perl script... BTW any idea what parsing method would make Perl choke when dealing with CRs?

Answer (score 2):

It could be a encoding issue when you are using `export-csv`

The default is `ASCII`, which should be fine usually, but try setting `-Encoding UTF8` in the `Export-CSV` command.

Comment: So you did not succeed? Or did you?

Comment: No I did not succeed. The solution was to remove the CR from the CSV. (See answer above)

Answer (score 1):

From [CPAN Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV):

```
use Text::CSV;

my @rows;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
             or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
  $row->[2] =~ m/pattern/ or next; # 3rd field should match
  push @rows, $row;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
```

Never try to parse CSV yourself, it seems easy at first glance but has a lot of deep pits to fall into.

Comment: I haven't written the perl script that imports the Csv, only the export script (powershell). The import script came with the nConf software package. Maybe I am missing something here but I'm unsure if your answer has provided a solution to the problem?

Comment: @Sune You didn't mention this in your original posting. My posting assumes that you can edit the perl script.

Answer (score 0):

Excel tends to assume that files saved in the .csv format are indeed comma-delimited.  However, it seems you are using semicolons.  You can try switching to commas, or if that is not an option, try changing the extension to .txt.  Excel should automatically recognize it if you do the former, whereas the latter will take you through the import wizard upon loading the file.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I will be processing the file in Perl and I just use Excel to look at the contents for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Given what has been discovered through the other posts, I think your best bet is to:

1. Convert to a CSV string (which uses unix-y carriage returns rather than Windows)
2. Send that to a file, ensuring the encoding is not ASCII.

---

```
$str = $object | convertto-csv -notypeinformation | foreach-object { $_ -replace "`"","" } #
```

`foreach-object` is a hack to remove the extra quotes that `convertto-csv` adds. If your data may have double-quotes, you'll need to look at alternatives.

```
$str | out-file -filepath "path\to\newcsv" -encoding UTF8
```