# Running two -replace on one file

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
    if(Test-Path $filename ) {
    # Remove quotes (")
    (get-content $filename) -replace('"','') | Out-File $filename -Force  
    $allText = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filename") -replace "`r`n?", "`n" 
    $encoding = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding    
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText("$filename", $allText, $encoding)
}
```

but I think it's kinda nonsense to do two -replaces. Is there a way I can combine the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
if(Test-Path $filename ) {
$allText = ([IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filename") -replace "`r`n?", "`n") -replace '"','' 
$encoding = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding    
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("$filename", $allText, $encoding)
```

}

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't remove carriage returns and garbles the output.

Comment: Changed it to use do both replaces on the streamed I/O.

Comment: Removed -1 now that it works. This can be done in 1 line with 1 `-replace`. Check out my answer.

Comment: I saw it, but the OP's example implied that newlines may or may not follow the CR.  -replace "`r`n","`n" is the same as -repace "`r","" only if there is always a "`n" following the "`r", so I didn't use that.

Comment: \n will always follow \r in Windows EOL format. The snippet came from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957629/format-of-csv-not-correct).

Comment: That's not evident in the question.  If that's the case, why does the original code specify an option match on `n instead of a required match?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the script like this. Read the content, join with "`n" (so you don't need to replace it, because Powershel returns lines from`Get-Content`) and replace quotes:

```
$c = (get-content $filename) -join "`n" -replace '"',''
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($fileName, $c, [text.encoding]::ASCII)
```

Comment: I noticed I had to use `[IO.File]::ReadAllText` to replace the carriage returns. It doesn't work with `Get-Content`.

Comment: I also noticed that `Set-Content` adds a carriage return + line feed at the very end of the file so it doesn't work either. I had to use `[IO.File]::WriteAllText`.

Comment: There is no requirement that there should be no empty line at the end. It's well known that `Set-Content` behaves in this way.

Comment: The OP's snippet is converting to unix EOL format which should have line feeds only. `Set-Content` doesn't produce the right output in this case which is probably why `[IO.File]::WriteAllText` is there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 1 liner.

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllText( $filename , ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename) -replace "`r|""",''), [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

The regex matches carriage returns or double quotes using the bar character and removes them.

`Get-Content` isn't working with `-replace` to replace the carriage returns and `Set-Content` adds a carriage return + line feed at the very end of the file, so stick with `[IO.File]`.